# saving in File using class-python

Tags: python

I'm new to python language.
I want to save a line to a file and load a specific line of a file.
The problem is that I should read(load) a line of that file as object of another(Grade) class or save a line into file as object of another class(Grade)

I did it and I want to see if I did it in right!

```
class Grade():

    def __init__(self,student_id=0,course_id=0,score=0):
        self._student_id = student_id
        self._course_id = course_id
        self._score = score


    @property
    def get(self):
        return str(self._student_id)+" "+str(self._course_id)+" "+str(float(self._score))
    @property

    def student_id(self):
        return str(self._student_id)
    @property
    def course_id(self):
        return str(self._course_id)
    @property
    def score(self):
        return str(self._score)

    @student_id.setter
    def student_id(self,student_id: int):
        self._sutdent_id = student_id
    @course_id.setter
    def course_id(self,course_id: int):
        self._course_id = course_id
    @score.setter
    def score(self,score: float):
        self._score = score


class CourseUtil():

    def __init__(self):
        self._address = ''

    def set_file(self,address):
        self._address = address

    def load(self,line_number):
        fp = open(self._address)
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i+1 == line_number:
                stri= line.split(" ")
                stdid = int(stri[0])
                corid = int(stri[1])
                score = float(stri[2])
                #here I want to save the #object that passed as argument to a file is it right?
               grade = Grade(stdid,corid,score)
                fp.close()
                return(grade)
        return print("None")


    def save(self,grade):
        i = 0
        k = 0
        fp = open(self._address)
        for  j,line in enumerate(fp):
            k += 1
            if grade.student_id in line and grade.course_id in line:
                i += 1
                break
        fp.close()
        if k > 0:
            if i == 0:
                with open(self._address,"a") as f:
                    f.write("\n"+grade.get)
        elif k == 0 and i == 0:
            with open(self._address,"a") as f:
                f.write(grade.get)
```

In save function I checked if data is unique and I avoid using last \n in end of file

Comment: Just use `pickle`, or at least let `json` do the heavy lifting, don't invent your own serialization routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you're using of saving lines of class entries is inefficient. Instead, you can store your data in a better way. I am assuming each student id is unique and hashable (either a string or integer). So, you could simply have a dictionary that has all the information about each student:

```
student_information = {
    {student_id}: {
        course_id: {course_id},
        score: {score}
    },
    ... # more students
}
```

Now, if you want to fetch a student's information, you could simply do `student_information[student_id]` to get the data you needed. For instance, you could do:

```
grade = Grade(
    student_id, 
    student_information[student_id]["course_id"], 
    student_information[student_id]["score"]
)
```

You can easily set this dictionary as an instance variable of your `CourseUtil` class.

Now, @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned that you should use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to store that information (if you would like to go back to it later). Pickle allows you to store data like a dictionary into a files and load it. There is also [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) that can help you do the same thing.